# Cannot connect dockerized spring boot app to dockerized postgre sql

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml with two services:

```
version: '2'
services:

  stuffer:
    container_name: stuffer_container
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    environment:
     - spring.profiles.active=dev
    depends_on:
     - postgreDB

  postgreDB:
    container_name: postgreDB_container
    image: "postgres:9.6.2"
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
    expose:
     - "5432"
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_DB=stuffer
     - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root123
    volumes:
     - /home/iwaneez/postgreData:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

my app has application-dev.properties:

```
## Datasource config
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgreDB:5432/stuffer
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root123
```

When I run them both using

> docker-compose up

I get connection refused exception:

```
stuffer_container | Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
stuffer_container |     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:60) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
stuffer_container |     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:192) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
stuffer_container |     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runSchemaScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:92) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
stuffer_container |     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.init(DataSourceInitializer.java:83) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
stuffer_container |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
stuffer_container |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
stuffer_container |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
stuffer_container |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
stuffer_container |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
stuffer_container |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
stuffer_container |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
stuffer_container |     ... 61 common frames omitted
stuffer_container | Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
stuffer_container |     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
stuffer_container |     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:46) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
stuffer_container |     ... 71 common frames omitted
stuffer_container | Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
stuffer_container |     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:138) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:32) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:732) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:479) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
stuffer_container |     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
stuffer_container |     ... 72 common frames omitted
stuffer_container | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
stuffer_container |     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
stuffer_container |     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
stuffer_container |     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
stuffer_container |     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
stuffer_container |     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
stuffer_container |     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
stuffer_container |     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
stuffer_container |     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
stuffer_container |     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
stuffer_container |     at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:62) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:76) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
stuffer_container |     ... 91 common frames omitted
```

How can I connect the application to postgre both running in docker?

I also tried running ubuntu image as third service and could successfully connect to db using

```
telnet postgreDB 5432
```

so it looks like it is visible, but app still cannot connect to it.

Changing datasource url property from postgreDB to localhost like

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/stuffer
```

lets me connect the application to postgre from outside the docker, but I need them both running in docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by running

```
docker-compose build
```

before running

```
docker-compose up
```

The problem was that there was an old image pointing to postgre through *localhost*. And althought I changed the host in config to *postgreDB* it wasn't built during *up* command as I thought from the command manual.
So no change was reflected in result.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your datasource to `jdbc:postgresql://postgreDB:5432/stuffer`. docker-compose assigns a hostname to each container based on a provided alias, or if no alias is specified, it uses the service name as assigned in the docker-compose.yml. This is all within the network managed by the docker host.

Answer (score 1):

When you are running only postgresDB using docker, given that you have forwarded the ports, postgres is available on your host OS and you can access the service using `localhost:5432`

But when you are running using docker compose, every container is different and because of which you cannot access `localhost:5432` from you spring application container. In this case postgresDB is running in separate container and you need to access it using the IP address of the container.

But docker compose solves that problem for you when you have configured dependency between services, docker compose will add a host entry in your container, which means you can now access postgresDB using `postgresDB:5432` from you spring application container.

Looking at your `application-dev.properties` the config looks correct but the datasource url containing `localhost` will not work in case of docker compose.

Comment: Yes, I know this. I use postgreDB in my config, but still get the error. I only mentioned localhost as the only way for me to connect the db of course outside docker.